# Hover and click events overlap in responsive menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu, responsive-design

I have made an HTML5 responsive, 2 levels menu you can see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsam4k3L/17/). The wide screen version shows submenus upon **hovering** over the main menu items; the narrow screen (less then 768px) version shows submenus upon **clicking** the main menu items.

The function that does the event switch is:

```
function horizVert() {
    var event;
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    event = "click";
    $('nav,.navcontainer').addClass("vertical").removeClass("horizontal");
} else {
    event = "hover";
    $('nav').removeAttr("style");
    $('nav,.navcontainer').addClass("horizontal").removeClass("vertical");
    }
    $('nav ul li').removeClass("active");
    $('nav ul a').on(event, function () {
        $(this).parents('li').toggleClass("active");
    });
}
horizVert();
$(window).resize(horizVert);
```

As you can see, if you resize the window, the "event switch" does not happen right and the narrow menu reacts to *hover*.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use css 3 to determine the window width using media query and then apply classes accordingly? You will have a fluent code and an easier one to understand.

I'd recomment you to create a new class, or even in the existing one, add media query and apply new css when window is under 768.

Comment: I want the menu to react at hover for window width > 768px and on click window width < 768px. Your observation is useful, but off topic I'm afraid...

Comment: Well first of all, you should look how your code is reacting via developer tools. make sure all the css/attr are removed or added as supposed to. then check your condition against screen width, because the problem is in your condition. Try using else if syntax.